# Is ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org a Reputable Source?

Tags: ubuntu

We noticed [ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org](https://ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org) is linked to [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker/) on Raspberry Pi's Magpi, but we just wanted to double check, can we be sure that images downloaded from this site don't have security issues and/or malware/spyware?

Answer (score 1):

No program you download from the internet can be guaranteed to be free of malware/spyware.

Having said that it is a reputable source of open-source code. In most cases you could inspect the code and make your own.

There is some downside - Support is poor/non-existent. None of these have support for the current Pi3B+ Most of the offerings are out-of date (even by Debian standards which often lag other Linux implementations by years).

Read the FAQ on the site.